# Ajax get json file with auth

Tags: json, azure

Want to make a query to azure marketplace. The API authentification is empty user + passphrase. The return should be an json object. The code below returns "[object Object]" to the browser. Where is my mistake?

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/SearchWeb/v1/Web?Query=%keyword%27',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth("", "myaccountkeyhere"));
    },
    success: function (data) {
        JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
        document.write(data);
        console.log(data);
        }
    });

    function make_base_auth(user, password) {
        var tok = user + ':' + password;
        var hash = btoa(tok);
        return 'Basic ' + hash;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are document.writing the JSON object. 
You need:

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
document.write(jsonString);
console.log(jsonString);
```

I made a quick jsfiddle for this. Note that jsfiddle doesn't allow document.write but replace your key and you should see it working.

[jsfiddle for loading bing search via json](http://jsfiddle.net/57r1mkkp/)

```
function make_base_auth(user, password) {
  var tok = user + ':' + password;
  var hash = btoa(tok);
  return 'Basic ' + hash;
}   

function writeToDom(title, content) {
    $("#results").append("<div class='header'>" + title + ":</div><div><pre>" + content + "</pre></div>");
}

function showResults(evnt) {

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/Composite?Sources=%27web%27&Query=%27keyword%27',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth("", "YOURKEYHERE"));
    },
    success: function (data) {
       var search = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
       writeToDom('Json', search);
       alert(search);
       console.log(search);
        }
    });
}

$(function() {
   $(document).on("click", "#clickme", showResults); 
});
```